# Mind Tickle (based on probability and random process)

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Mr. X is on a number line. His current position is zero. With each step he takes he adds either 2 or 3 to the sum depending on whether he is stepping on an even or odd number respectively. What is the probability that at the 10th step the sum is 23? Note: sum = 0 in the beginning

Comment: So he has to come from tile 20 and step forward 3 tiles or from 21 and step forward 2? That is impossible.

Comment: What does this have to do with probability? The way I understand it his position goes 0, 2, 4, 6, ... perfectly deterministically.

Comment: sorry if i have framed it wrong. lets say he takes a step from 0 to 1 on the number line. since 1 is an odd number he adds 3 to the sum. Sum = 0 in the beggining i.e at step 0

Answer (score 1):

So basically Mr. X and the number line and the odds and even is all obfuscation.

What you have is running sum in which you can add 2 or 3 randomly.

In 10 steps what is the probability that the sum is 23?

Let N = the number of times you added 2, 10N = the number of times you added 3.  2N + 3(10 -N) = 30 - N = 23 so N = 7.  You added 2 seven times and you added 3 three times.

There are 8 positions (3 ... 10) in which you could have added the last 3.  Call it 2 + a (a = 1...8).  There are a positions (2... 2+a - 1) you could have placed the second.  Call it 1 + b (b= 1... a).  And there are b positions you can place the 3rd.  (1.... b).

So the number of ways is $\sum_{a=1}^8\sum_{b=1}^a\sum_{c=1}^b 1 = \sum_{a=1}^8\sum_{b=1}^a b = \sum_{a=1}^8 b(b+1)/2 = 1 + 3 + 6 + 10 + 15 + 21 + 28 + 36 = 120$  So the probability is $120/2^{10} = 120/1024 = 15/128$.

Answer (score 0):

Still, as Mees de Vries said, there is no "probability" involved.  Or are you saying that the **length** of the step is random?  Is so what probability distribution?

If he is just making one step at a time, he will step to 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, and 10.  Exactly 5 of those, 1, 3, 5, 7 and 9, are odd so he will add 3(5)= 15.  Exactly 5 of those, 2, 4, 5, 9, 10, are even so he will add 2(5)= 10.  When he gets to the 10th step his sum will be 15+ 10= 25.  The sum **cannot** be 23.

Again, there is no "probability" involved.

Comment: Yes sir... Length of the step is random...